# Probabilities above $1$

Tags: probability, notation

Is it okay for a probability to be above one, where all probabilities above one are equivalent to a probability of one? If not, is it okay to write something like this:

$$P(Q) = \begin{cases} \displaystyle \frac ab, &  \text{if} \ \ \displaystyle \frac ab \le 1 \\[2ex] 1, &\text{if} \ \ \displaystyle  \frac ab > 1 \end{cases} $$

**EDIT:**

In a comment, I said:

> I think that a probability above 1 has been established as non-sensical in the comments, or non-standard (pretty sure my theorem works within standard probability theory). As such, my question defers to whether the given expression is allowed.

This was answered by Ethan Bolker, and I was planning on accepting his answer. However, the nature of $Q$ seems to be of relevance, hence my reluctance to do so, and the previous edit I made, shown below:

I posted [the theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4321311/probability-that-an-element-of-one-set-is-in-a-different-set-both-within-a-fini) I was working on here. In it you can see what caused this conundrum. According to Ethan Bolker's answer, there was no problem in using the piecewise expression, so I did that.

Comment: Probabilities larger than $1$ are as nonsensical as negative probabilities (that are sadly actually claimed to occur in quantum physics). Probabilities lie in the interval $[0,1]$ per definition.

Comment: @Peter "Probabilities larger than 1 are as nonsensical (...)", that's what I thought too. However, in a theorem of mine, I ended up with an expression that sometimes evaluates to more than one. I of course wondered if it was wrong, but upon inspection, I still haven't been able to see that is incorrect.

Comment: The domain of Q (x?) is missing. Something like $...<Q\leq ...$

Comment: Sure that the expression is actually a formula for a probability ? Maybe, it is only an ESTIMATE for a probability. Although estimates usually also lie in the interval $[0,1]$

Comment: @Peter According to my knowledge, it is a probability and not an estimate of one. I haven't really encountered probability estimates however, so I can't say for sure.

Comment: @callculus42 Not sure what you mean. $Q$ is a statement, how can it have a numerical value?

Comment: @user110391 Not sure what you mean with statement. As I said you need a domain for the variable.

Comment: @callculus42 By statement I mean stuff like "$x$ is an even number". So then $P(Q)$ would be the probability that $x$ is an even number.

Comment: @user110391 As long as Q is not defined it is hard to say if the cdf(?) is valid. Make an edit and we will see if the pdf is valid.

Comment: @user110391 the standard probability theory deals with probabilities inside $[0,1]$ range only. If you've encountered a probability outside of that range then either you are dealing with some non-standard theory (but then I suppose you wouldn't be asking the question) or you've made a mistake (which may also mean that there's a mistake in a calculation made by someone else that you are using).

Comment: @callculus42 I think giving the statement that led to this conundrum in the theorem I'm working on right now would derail this question away from generality. I think that a probability above $1$ has been established as non-sensical in the comments, or non-standard (pretty sure my theorem works within standard probability theory). As such, my question defers to whether the given expression is allowed. Now, surely what $Q$ is doesn't matter. It is given that $ P(Q) = \frac ab \iff \frac ab \le 1$ and $ \frac ab > 1 \implies P(Q) = 1 $. In this case, is the featured piecewise expression allowed?

Answer (score 1):

A probability is a special case of an expected value.  Say you're picking balls from an urn and looking to see whether they are red.  The probability of a red ball is exactly the expected number of red balls per pick.

If you are picking two balls at a time, you can still speak of the expected number of red balls per pick and it could be as high as $2$.  That's no longer a probability, but it's closely related to one; you can see that the two situations are very similar.

You didn't tell us what your original question was, that provided the context for your “probability greater than 1”. It's possible that what you really have is an expected value and you are confusing it with a probability.

For a better answer, try asking a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment (that should really be part of the question you clarify:

> As such, my question defers to whether the given expression is
> allowed.

There is no mathematical problem at all with the piecewise expression you are using to define a probability.

Whether that cutoff makes sense when $a>b$ depends on what $a$ and $b$ mean in your context.